# How can I open large (2GB) files and precompute it quicker?

Tags: python, matlab, processing, h5py, buffering

This is the code I am currently using to open this very large matlab file:

```py
self.data = {}
f = h5py.File(filepath, 'r')
for k, v in f.items():
    self.data[k] = np.array(v)
self.data = list(self.data.items())
self.data = np.array(self.data)
self.fs = self.data[1][1][0][0]
self.data = self.data[0][1]

print('fs = ', self.fs)
print('DONE. Data read using h5py reader')
```

It takes about 3-5 minutes to load fully. How can I improve this code so I can speed up the process?

Comment: since your code works without error, you could try posting the question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Short answer is you can't. Disk I/O is what it is

Comment: @jsotola, I don't think this is a CR suitable question.  It's too specialized.

Comment: You do a lot more than "open" the file. You read all the root level datasets as np.arrays and add to dictionary `self.data`. Then the dictionary is converted to a list, and a new array is created from the list. That means you are reading and manipulating 2GB of data. As @Mad Physicist said: _Disk I/O is what it is_ (and it's not fast). Do you need to read all at once? h5py is designed to access and work with HDF5 datasets "like" NumPy arrays. In your code, `v`is a h5py object that behaves like an array (without loading into memory). Save the objects only, and it will load much faster.

Comment: how would I go about saving the objects only?

Comment: Tessa, I missed your comment. Sorry. See answer for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Saving and using objects is easy. It's hard to provide specifics about objects vs arrays without knowing the purpose of your code. What do you want to do with variable `self.data` after you get it? You retrieve all of the datasets, then keep redefining `self.data`. At the end, you assign `self.data` to an array for the 1st dataset. Also, `self.fs` points to a single value from the 2nd dataset. So, it's not clear why you retrieve all of them.

If you only want the data from the first dataset, something like this will do the job.

```
f = h5py.File(filepath, 'r')
# returns first key from group member names:
dsname = next(iter(f))    #  (name of 1st dataset)
self.data = f[dsname][:]  #  (data from 1st dataset)
```

If you want the name and data from all the datasets, this will return a dictionary of names and objects.

```
f = h5py.File(filepath, 'r')
for k, v in f.items():
    self.data[k] = v
```

Then, when you need an array of data, use one of these methods:

```
arr = data['a dataset name'][:]  # for 1 dataset (when you know the name)
for dsname, obj in data.items():  # loop thru all pairs in data
    arr = obj[:]  # or
    arr = f[dsname][:]
```

To understand what's going on, let's start with some HDF5 basics. It's critically important to understand the schema when working with HDF5. The data structure is similar to folders and files on a computer. The Folders are "Groups" and the Files are "Datasets".  With h5py, you ***access Groups members using dictionary syntax***, and you ***access Datasets with NumPy array syntax***. (The h5py File object behaves like a Group.)

So, when you execute `for k,v in f.items()`, h5py returns `key,value` pairs for each group member (`k,v` in your code).  The `key` is the **object's name** and the `value` is a **h5py object** (either a dataset or another group).

Once you have a dataset, there are 3 ways to access the associated data:

1. You can simply save the object and reference it "as-if" it is a NumPy
   array.
2. You can save the object's name, then when you need the object's data, you retrieve using the dataset name and associated group.
3. You can read the dataset values into a NumPy array. (This is what your code does.)

Note: I prefer Methods #1 and #2 because they ***do not load the data into memory*** until you read the data.

Here is your code with my comments about each step:

```
# returns a file object "f" (behaves like a group):
f = h5py.File(filepath, 'r')
# returns key/value pairs of group member names/objects:
for k, v in f.items():
    # adds a dictionary key (object name) with value of an array read from object "v":
    self.data[k] = np.array(v)
# converts the (name,array) dictionary into a list:
self.data = list(self.data.items())
# converts the list into a nd.array of dtype=object:
#    -has 1 row for each dataset with 2 columns: 
#    -column 0: object name, column 1: array of data 
self.data = np.array(self.data)
# reads [0][0] value from array at self.data[1][1] ([0][0] value for 2nd dataset)
self.fs = self.data[1][1][0][0]
# resets data to value from array at self.data[0][1] (array for 1st dataset)
self.data = self.data[0][1]
```